# After upgrade Angular to 11 from 10. I get Argument of type 'Subject<void>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ObservableInput<any>'

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this line of code in almost every component file where I have subscribe to an observable returning from singleton service file.

`destroy$ : Subject<void> = new Subject<void>()`

```
this._sessionService.toggleMeetingBar.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$)).subscribe(result => {
      this.barType = "meetingBar";
      this._sideNav.toggle();
})
```

```
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.destroy$.next();
    this.destroy$.complete();
  }
```

schedule-session.service.ts

```
  public toggleMeetingBar = new Subject<any>();


    this._session.upsertSession(sessionData).subscribe(result => {
      this.toggleMeetingBar.next(false);
    });
```

Now after upgrading to Angular 11. I get below error flooded in my terminal. There are many other issue regarding Firestore. But I am more concern with this one. I did this to clear the memory when the component is destroyed.

```
Error: src/app/shared/components/auto-complete/auto-complete.component.ts:77:34 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'Subject<void>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ObservableInput<any>'.
  Type 'Subject<void>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<any>'.

77         .pipe(take(1), takeUntil(this._onDestroy))
```

How can I fixed this error ?

My package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
        "@angular-material-components/datetime-picker": "5.1.0",
        "@angular/animations": "^11.2.12",
        "@angular/cdk": "^11.2.11",
        "@angular/common": "11.2.12",
        "@angular/compiler": "11.2.12",
        "@angular/core": "11.2.12",
        "@angular/fire": "^6.1.4",
        "@angular/forms": "11.2.12",
        "@angular/material": "11.2.11",
        "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "11.2.11",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "11.2.12",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "11.2.12",
        "@angular/router": "11.2.12",
        "@filestack/angular": "^1.3.0",
        "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.8.2",
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.3",
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.35",
        "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.15.3",
        "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.3",
        "@fullcalendar/angular": "5.6.0",
        "@fullcalendar/core": "5.6.0",
        "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "5.6.0",
        "@fullcalendar/interaction": "5.6.0",
        "@fullcalendar/list": "5.6.0",
        "@fullcalendar/moment": "5.6.0",
        "@fullcalendar/rrule": "5.6.0",
        "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "5.6.0",
        "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-navigations": "^19.1.58",
        "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-progressbar": "^19.1.57",
        "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-richtexteditor": "^19.1.57",
        "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-splitbuttons": "^19.1.54",
        "@syncfusion/ej2-layouts": "^19.1.58",
        "@types/jspdf": "^1.3.3",
        "@types/stripe": "^8.0.416",
        "apexcharts": "^3.26.1",
        "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
        "crypto-js": "4.0.0",
        "filestack-js": "^3.23.1",
        "firebase": "^8.4.3",
        "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
        "highlight.js": "10.7.2",
        "jquery": "^3.6.0",
        "jspdf": "^2.3.1",
        "lodash-es": "4.17.21",
        "moment": "^2.29.1",
        "ng-apexcharts": "^1.5.9",
        "ng-circle-progress": "^1.6.0",
        "ng-starrating": "^1.0.20",
        "ng-stripe-checkout": "^1.0.4",
        "ng-wistia-components": "0.0.2",
        "ngx-device-detector": "^2.0.8",
        "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^10.0.1",
        "ngx-markdown": "11.1.3",
        "ngx-mat-select-search": "^3.2.0",
        "ngx-moment": "^5.0.0",
        "ngx-pagination": "^5.0.0",
        "ngx-quill": "^13.3.1",
        "ngx-sharebuttons": "^8.0.5",
        "ngx-toastr": "^13.2.1",
        "perfect-scrollbar": "1.5.0",
        "quill": "1.3.7",
        "rrule": "2.6.8",
        "rxjs": "7.0.0",
        "stripe": "^8.145.0",
        "stripe-angular": "^1.7.0",
        "tslib": "2.2.0",
        "web-animations-js": "2.3.2",
        "zone.js": "0.11.4"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.1102.11",
        "@angular/cli": "11.2.11",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "11.2.12",
        "@angular/language-service": "11.2.12",
        "@types/crypto-js": "4.0.1",
        "@types/highlight.js": "9.12.4",
        "@types/jasmine": "3.6.10",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.8",
        "@types/lodash-es": "4.17.4",
        "@types/node": "15.0.1",
        "codelyzer": "6.0.2",
        "jasmine-core": "3.7.1",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "7.0.0",
        "karma": "6.3.2",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "3.1.0",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "3.0.3",
        "karma-jasmine": "4.0.1",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "1.5.4",
        "lodash": "^4.17.21",
        "protractor": "7.0.0",
        "tailwindcss": "2.1.2",
        "ts-node": "9.1.1",
        "tslint": "6.1.2",
        "typescript": "^4.1.5"
    }
```

Basic import

```
import { Component, HostListener, Inject, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Sessions } from "../../../customApi/sessions";
import { SessionLogsService } from '../session-logs.service';
import { Utils } from 'app/shared/utils/utils';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import { UserConstant } from 'app/user.constant';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
import { ReplaySubject, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Comment: I see that you've updated the error message. Nevertheless this seems interesting. Try: `takeUntil(this.destroy$.asObservable())`

Comment: I reverted it. Even after updating it shows same error. `http://prntscr.com/12gwroa`

Comment: Can you show us the import statements?

Comment: I updated with import. Is that what you wanted to see ?

Comment: How is it with RxJS v6?

Comment: yes, please share the toggleMeetingBar from the service.

Comment: I have updated it.

Comment: Try: In service: `private toggleMeetingBar: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>(); public toggleMeetingBar$: Observable<any> = this.toggleMeetingBar.asObservable();`. In component: `this._sessionService.toggleMeetingBar$.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))`

Comment: same error `http://prntscr.com/12gyo0f`

Comment: Since rxjs is still in beta version, I think you should not update rxjs to version 7 for production app. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/41897

Comment: @kvetis  After downgrading to version rxjs 6.5.5 as before its fixed.

Comment: Great news. Btw @Chellappanவ: RxJS v7 has been released 5 days ago.

Comment: Hey @kvetis Thanks for the info. I checked in npm, It's showing stable version is pointing to 6.x whereas master pointing to v7. https://www.npmjs.com/package/rxjs/v/7.0.0.

Comment: Well I guess they release the 7.0.0 (the version is marked as stable) and forgot to update the readme.  ‍♂️

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use a boolean, so onDestroy you cast  this.destroy$.next(true). i'm following this guide

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-takeuntil-rxjs-unsubscribe

Comment: Getting this error. ` Argument of type 'ReplaySubject<any>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ObservableInput<any>'.`

Comment: try to use a boolean, so onDestroy you cast a this.destroy$.next(true). i'm following this guide https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-takeuntil-rxjs-unsubscribe

Comment: Please update this as your answer. This is what I was planning to do but again I see this as your comment to be sure. RXJS v 7.0.1 now requires .next() with a value as an argument. Thanks for commenting.

Comment: glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

I want to confess my sins.

I had used [`ncu -u`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates) to update my `package.json`. So this command when run in your application it will update version of each packages to latest available version.

As suggested by @kvetis and @Chellappan I downgrade `rxjs` version from 7 to 6.5.5 (stable) and it worked fine. Also I had to downgrade typescript to 4.1.5

Everything worked fine after this.

Thanks to everybody who commented.

EDITED:

Below RXJS version 7

```
destroy$ : Subject<void> = new Subject<void>()
ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.destroy$.next();
    this.destroy$.complete();
  }
```

RXJS version 7.1.0

```
destroy$ : Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>()
ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.destroy$.next(true);
    this.destroy$.complete();
  }
```

To avoid error.

[Credit link digitalocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-takeuntil-rxjs-unsubscribe)

Comment: Well I think this is a bug on the RxJS side in combination with strictFunctionTypes TS setting. What you're doing should work in v7. I'd create a repro example and file it, but I was not able to reproduce the issue on stackblitz.

Comment: With RXJS v7.0.1 the `this.destroy$.next();` should now be `this.destroy$.next(true);`. The argument is compulsory .

Comment: I'd like to add here, I had a slightly different problem, but it was my own silliness.

Double check your reference to Subject, I had
```import { Subject } from '@microsoft/signalr';```
instead of 
```import { Subject } from 'rxjs';```

Hope that helps someone save 20  min.